# Typescript Index Signature with Complex Data Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an index signature question related to some data to display in a React table, where the periods need to be transposed from the row data into columns - 100 time periods become 100 columns.  The table becomes 'type' in the rows, 100 periods in the columns and amount is the value shown for each. The data type is shown below, along with the DisplayData object which uses an index signature to help the transformation of all 100 columns be written in one statement with pivotedObj[obj.period].

```
export interface IData {
type: string;
period: number;
amount: number;
otherDataOfInterest1: number;
otherDataOfInterest2: number;
}
```

```
export interface IDisplayData {
type: string;
[period: string]: string;
'1': string;
'2': string;
....
'100': string;
}
```

The code to transform it is:

```
uniqueTypes.forEach((item) => { pivotedData.push(
originalData.reduce((pivotedObj, obj) => {
if(item === obj['type']){
pivotedObj['type'] = obj['type];
pivotedObj[obj.period] = pivotedObj[obj.period] ? obj['amount']: 0;
}
return pivotedObj
}, {}))
```

This leads to having the amount property being displayed in the grid successfully.  The question comes from now needing to pass more than just amount into the grid.  Something like:

```
interface INewDataToDisplay {
amount: number;
otherDataOfInterest1: number;
otherDataOfInterest2: number;
}
```

So instead of inserting the amount into pivotedObj[obj.period], you would insert an object of type INewDataToDisplay and you'd have to update the index signature of IDisplayData because it is no longer a string value for each column. This is where the question is, how do you transform the definition of IDisplayData to allow the index signature to keep working without getting the error on all 100 period properties of type INewDataToDisplay that "property ''1'' of type 'INewDataToDisplay' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string"? If you switch to [period: string]: INewDataToDisplay then the error switches to the 'type' property not being INewDataToDisplay so would there be some way to exclude it?

```
export interface IDisplayData {
type: string;
[period: string]: string; ---> what has to change here?
'1': INewDataToDisplay;
'2': INewDataToDisplay;
....
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to exclude keys from an index signature this way, despite a longstanding feature request at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  There are various workarounds, see the answers to the linked question